# TypeError: _firebase_firebase_utils_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.auth.onAuthStateChange is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, import, firebase-authentication

I'm developing my very first React App and have encounter this error which I can't understand:

> TypeError:firebase_firebase_utils_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.auth.onAuthStateChange is not a function

I have tried deleting my node_modules folder and reinstalling it. Also importing firebase with Node.js' `require()` syntax. With no different result. I read some other *StackOverflow* articles that said something about 'firebase-admin' but I haven't installed such a dependency.

**firebase.utils.js**

```
    import firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import 'firebase/firestore';
    import 'firebase/auth';

    const config = {...}

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    export const auth = firebase.auth();
    export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });

    export const signInWithGoogle = () =>  auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

    export default firebase;
   ===================================
```

The code breaked when I added this: to my **App.js**

```
    {...}

   import { auth } from './firebase/firebase.utils.js';

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super();

       this.state = {
          currentUser: null
      }
     }

      //The code breaks here!
      componentDidMount() {
        auth.onAuthStateChange(user => {
         this.setState({ currentUser: user });


        })
      }
    {...}
```

I suppose that I need to know where the `onAuthStateChange()` method lives an how to bring it to my `App.js` file, but I'm not really sure that's the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is called `onAuthStateChanged` with a `d` at the end. See [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) in the documentation.